# Upgrade to 13.04 was not successful. Gstreamer not working. What do?

Tags: installation, 13.04, upgrade, rhythmbox, gstreamer

I finally decided to upgrade to 13.04. In the middle of the installation my computer froze completely, and so I decided to force quit. I log back on, and notice that the login says 13.04, but not everything was updated. So I run the software updater. Some of the stuff gets updated, but not everything, I suppose. I try to run Rhythmbox, but it says that it's not able to form playback, and that the Gstreamer was messed up, and to please check installation. I don't know what other bugs maybe running. That's just the first I've encountered. The software updater won't let me update anymore because it says the updates need authentication.

Answer (score 1):

Please post your `sources.list` file which is located in `/etc/apt`. And try `apt-get -f install`.

Comment: How can I add the file? Unless you mean copy and paste. I ran the command, and it showed that 8 things have not been upgraded, but it only gave me the option to remove a few things. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @user172214, you can use [Ubuntu pastebin](http://paste.ubuntu.com) or [Pastebin itself](http://pastebin.com) to upload file there, then copy link here.

Comment: I read precise pangolin somewhere in there. http://paste.ubuntu.com/5839426/

Comment: @user172214, it seems to me that everything with this file is OK. Now you should run `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` to update all packages.

Comment: :/ nothing is being done. Is there any way I can fun a full scan of the system?

Comment: @user172214, then try `dpkg --configure -a` then reboot and, if it does not help, post the output of `dpkg --list`. You should edit your initial post to do this, as AskUbuntu recommends.

Comment: I'll try that. I installed Clementine, and it works fine. Does Clementine use Gstreamer?